# How to Move Code that Modifies View to Main Class

Tags: java, android, textview

So, as I'm completely new to Android development, I wanted to create a simple application for my new Moto 360 (Google Wear) to display some content pulled from a webpage. Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

How would I go about moving the part that modifies the text value of the `TextView` to the main class?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.round_activity_my);

    TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    myAsyncTask mTask = new myAsyncTask();
    mTask.execute("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");


    /* final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }); */
}
```

and the `AsyncTask` class is

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... str) {
        TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                mTextView.setText(reader.readLine());
                webs.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                mTextView.setText("HI");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mTextView.setText(e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update UI from `doInBackground`. Move that code to `onPostExecute`

```
//In doInBackground

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    resultText = reader.readLine();
    webs.close();
} catch(Exception e){
    resultText = "HI";
}
.  
.
.
// onPostExecute method
protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
    mTextView.setText(resultText);
}
```

Declare `resultText` as a global String

Comment: @Holabola There's no need to declare `resultText` as a global String. `doInBackground()` returns values to `onPostExecute()` so the result can just be returned and use `str` from the `param` list of `onPostExecute()` to set the text.

Answer (score 1):

The doInBackground() method is performed on a background thread - not the UI thread. Only the UI thread can modify the views.

The AyncTask class provides the onProgressUpdate() method and the onPostExecute() method that hook onto the UI thread to show progress or results (respectively).

If you want to show progress as the AsyncTask is executing, move the code that sets the text in your TextView to the onProgressUpdate() method. If you want it to show at the end of the execution of the AsyncTask, then move it to onPostExecute().